# How to search in multiple domains using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement?

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap

I have three or more domains like `main.com`, `sub.main.com`, `sub2.main.com` and etc

I have a code:

```
using (PrincipalContext ctx = 
    new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "ADServer", 
    "dc=main,dc=com", ContextOptions.Negotiate))
{
    UserPrincipal u = new UserPrincipal(ctx);
    u.UserPrincipalName = "*" + mask + "*";

    using (PrincipalSearcher ps = new PrincipalSearcher(u))
    {
       PrincipalSearchResult<Principal> results = ps.FindAll();
       List<ADUser> lst = new List<ADUser>();

       foreach (var item in results.Cast<UserPrincipal>().Take(15))
       {
           byte[] sid = new byte[item.Sid.BinaryLength];
           item.Sid.GetBinaryForm(sid, 0);

           ADUser us = new ADUser()
           {
               Sid = sid,
               Account = item.SamAccountName,
               FullName = item.DisplayName
           };

           lst.Add(us);
       }

    }

    return lst;
}
```

But it searches within only one domain: `main.com`.

How can I search records in all domains at one time?

Comment: I don't think you can search in multiple domains at one time. You need to "serialize" your searches.

Comment: do you mean that i have to know the domains and search them with cycle?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is a way to find all your domains from the root one :

```
/* Retreiving RootDSE
 */
string ldapBase = "LDAP://DC_DNS_NAME:389/";
string sFromWhere = ldapBase + "rootDSE";
DirectoryEntry root = new DirectoryEntry(sFromWhere, "AdminLogin", "PWD");
string configurationNamingContext = root.Properties["configurationNamingContext"][0].ToString();

/* Retreiving the root of all the domains
 */
sFromWhere = ldapBase + configurationNamingContext;
DirectoryEntry deBase = new DirectoryEntry(sFromWhere, "AdminLogin", "PWD");

DirectorySearcher dsLookForDomain = new DirectorySearcher(deBase);
dsLookForDomain.Filter = "(&(objectClass=crossRef)(nETBIOSName=*))";
dsLookForDomain.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;
dsLookForDomain.PropertiesToLoad.Add("nCName");
dsLookForDomain.PropertiesToLoad.Add("dnsRoot");

SearchResultCollection srcDomains = dsLookForDomain.FindAll();

foreach (SearchResult aSRDomain in srcDomains)
{
}
```

Then foreach domain, you can look for what you need.

Comment: No `:389` port in my case.

Comment: You should find the GC on your domain.

Comment: Thanks, also `new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://server IP/DC=my-domain,DC=com", ...)` worked fine.

Answer (score 27):

You should use GC instead of LDAP. It searches along whole Domain Forest

```
var path = "GC://DC=main,DC=com";

try
{
    using (var root = new DirectoryEntry(path, username, password))
    {
        var searchFilter = string.Format("(&(anr={0})(objectCategory=user)(objectClass=user))", mask);
        using (var searcher = new DirectorySearcher(root, searchFilter, new[] { "objectSid", "userPrincipalName" }))
        {
            var results = searcher.FindAll();
            foreach (SearchResult item in results)
            {
                //What ever you do
            }
        }
    }
}

catch (DirectoryServicesCOMException)
{
    // username or password are wrong
}
```

Comment: Thanks this works like a charm and is simpler than the accepted answer.

Comment: Up voted for visibility. Best answer after searching through lot of resources

Answer (score 2):

To actually use System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement to do the search, specify the domain as such:

```
new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "xyz.mycorp.com:3268", "DC=mycorp,DC=com");
```

From
[When do I need a Domain Name and a Domain Container to create a PrincipalContext?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23559710/when-do-i-need-a-domain-name-and-a-domain-container-to-create-a-principalcontext)