# Enumerating domains in a forest (windows networks)

Tags: winapi, active-directory, windows-networking

I looking for an API method that retrieve the info that "net view /domain" does.
namely, I'm looking for a way to enumerate the visible domains within a forest, using win32api (in C environment)

thanks.

**Update:**
it seems that [DsEnumerateDomainTrusts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675976%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) can do what I need, however, it doesn't looks like net.exe importing it, so I'd still like to know of other options.

**Update2:**
as it's name imply, the function only enumerate trusted domain, even when DS_DOMAIN_IN_FOREST is specified,
so I'm in square 1.

Answer (score 2):

I think that in your case the best way is to interrogate Active directory.

You will find in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10527365/608772) the way to get all the domains in your directory, first requesting "rootDSE" to find the configuration naming context, second requesting for `crossRef` with `nETBIOSName` to retreive domain entries

As you are interested in how to interrogate active directory from native code, you may have a look to LDAP C-Binding API as discribed in RFC 1823 specifies, Microsoft support it, see [MS Strategy for Lightweight Directory Access Protocol (LDAP)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc750824.aspx). You'll find the using and reference manuals of the [Microsoft API in Lightweight Directory Access Protocol](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367008%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).